# Evitar que un método con el mismo nombre se muestre al llamarlo

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenas necesito ayuda por favor, como evito que cunado llamo a aun metodo de un hijo que tiene el mismo nombre en el padre pero con diferentes parametros se mustre al llamar el metodo del hijo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clase padre:

```
public class Arreglo {
protected int cantidad;
protected Integer []vector;

public Arreglo(int cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.vector = new Integer[cantidad];
}
public Integer getvalor(int indice){
    if(indice<this.cantidad){
        return vector[indice];
    }
    return null;
}
        
 public boolean insertarorden(int indice,int valor ){
    if(indice<this.cantidad){
    vector[indice]=valor;
    return  true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void mostrardatos(){
 for (int i = 0; i < this.cantidad; i++) {
    System.out.println("vector["+i+"]= "+vector[i]);
    }

   }
  }
```

Clase hijo

```
public class ArregloOrden extends Arreglo{
private int pos;
public ArregloOrden(int cantidad) {
    super(cantidad);
    this.pos=0;
}


public boolean insertarorden( int valor) {
     if(this.pos<this.cantidad){
    vector[pos]=valor;
    pos++;
    return true;
    }
     return false;
}   
}
```

Entonces lo que necesito es evitar que cuando lo llame con el mismo nombre no aparezca el método del padre solo el de hijo

Comment: La imagen es demasiado pequeña. ¿Puedes colocar una con mayor resolución? También, publica el código que estás utilizando actualmente para ver cómo puede modificarse.

Comment: Ya esta mi estimado

Comment: Si te refieres a que en netbeans te aparece en el listado el método del padre, eso no se puede evitar ya que como usas la clase hija te mostrara los métodos de la clase padre, solo selecciona el que te interesa y listo.

Comment: SI a eso msmo me refiria gracias

Answer (score 0):

pues dependiendo el número de parámetros que la pases a tu función ya que ves que en la clase padre tiene dos y en la hija solo 1, además de esto recuerda manejar bien las instancias para manipular tus métodos.